# Sequelize.js onDelete: 'cascade' is not deleting records sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am having `Product` table with following columns `[id, name, CategoryId]` and `Category` table with `[id, name]`

Product Model:-

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    associate: function(models) {
      Product.belongsTo(models.Category);
    }
  });
  return Product
}
```

Category Model:-

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }
  }, {
    associate: function(models) {
      Category.hasMany(models.Product, { onDelete: 'cascade' });
    }
  });
  return Category
}
```

when I delete category, it deletes category only not the corresponding products associated with it. I don't know why this is happening?

update:
Sequelize Version `sequelize 1.7.0`

================================================================================
**Answer**(How this I have fixed.):-

I accomplished this by adding constraint on database using `Alter` command, as `Add Foreign Key Constraint` through `migration` is an open [bug](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/966) in `sequelize`.

```
ALTER TABLE "Products"
ADD CONSTRAINT "Products_CategoryId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("CategoryId")
REFERENCES "Categories" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Whats the output of sequelize.sync? Is it adding a foreign key with an on delete constraint? What version are you on?

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier Product table is having `CategoryId` column but foreign key constraint is not added. how to add foreign key with delete constraint?

Comment: Do I need to add migration for adding foreign key constraint?

Comment: @Sampat, the way you edited this question is confusing. If agchou's answer worked you should have accepted that as an answer instead of modifying your question to look like it never had a bug in the code. It will make it more clear for others to see a question containing a problem, and an accepted answer that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 44):

I believe you are supposed to put the onDelete in the Category model instead of in the products model.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false }
  }, {
    associate: function(models) {
      Category.hasMany(models.Product, { onDelete: 'cascade' });
    }
  });
  return Category
}
```

Comment: this wasn't working for me until I added `hooks: true` as well. Not sure if that's a bug or by design

Comment: If I have a `User` model that `hasMany()` a lot of things, is there an easy solution than go to every model and add `onDelete: "cascade"` in the `belongsTo()`?

Answer (score 32):

I'm on Sequelize 4.38.0.

I had to put `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` not only on the association definition, but as well in the migration file.

```
// in models/user.js
User.associate = models => {
  User.belongsTo(models.Organization, {
    foreignKey: { name: 'organizationId', allowNull: true },
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
}

// in migrations/create-users.js
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
    // other fields...
    organizationId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      references: {
        model: 'Organizations',
        key: 'id',
        as: 'organizationId',
      },
    },
  })
},
```

Comment: I have once ran the migration file and now i am adding `onDelete: 'CASCADE',` this in it. So will re-running it add this thing to the table in my DB without messing any other thing up?

Answer (score 15):

As of "sequelize": "^3.5.1", it only works when you put `onDelete='CASCADE'` in the `belongsTo` declaration, which is the `Product` model in your case. This contradicts the docs: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/associations/index.html?highlight=onDelete#hasmanytarget-options

Please see this question:[Sequelize onDelete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634139/sequelize-ondelete-not-working)

Comment: It worked fine for me with hasMany(), but I had to add "hooks: true" to the option. Like User.hasOne(Profile, {onDelete: 'cascade', hooks:true})

Comment: Like @SoichiHayashi, `{onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true}` on the `hasMany` association worked for me. I'm on Sequelize "3.30". Having the associations the other way around actually caused me some issues.

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is some time migration script generated missing `CONSTRAINT` for `foreign key`.

I'm still getting issue event follow [official document](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/hooks.html#associations) for `{ onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true }`.

Here's my solution:

Step 1: Create migration files as usual but no `foreign key` yet. Remember defined `associate` as you did

```
    Product.belongsTo(models.Category);

    Category.hasMany(models.Product);
```

Step 2: Create migration script to add the `foreign key` column into table:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Product', // name of Source model
      'categoryId', // name of the key we're adding 
      {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Category', // name of Target model
          key: 'id', // key in Target model that we're referencing
        },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      }
    );
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn(
      'Product', // name of Source model
      'categoryId' // key we want to remove
    );
  }
};
```

Hope this help!

I found this solution by combine from:

- [[Express.js][Sequelize] How to delete child records ( cascade deleting ) at the time of deleting parent record.](https://its-all-writing.com/archives/178) (dead link)
- [How to define Sequelize associations using migrations](https://medium.com/@andrewoons/how-to-define-sequelize-associations-using-migrations-de4333bf75a7)

Comment: It Works! Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, but had to put a plural name. `references: {model: 'Questions'}` worked for me, but `references: {model: 'Question'}` didn't.

Answer (score 5):

I finally figured it wasn't working for me because of paranoid. Sequelize doesn't handle `cascade`, and does a MySQL cascade delete instead. With that said, if you use paranoid with your tables - cascade won't happen since the records are not really deleted from the table.

Comment: i miss Hibernate so hard

Comment: Sequelize is an abomination.

Answer (score 5):

On `hasMany` association add `onDelete` cascade and set hooks to true like this

```
 Category.hasMany(models.Product, { onDelete: 'cascade', hooks:true });
```

Comment: This works but using {hooks:true} has bad impact on performance. Checkout here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html

Answer (score 3):

To delete the parent record and also delete the child records.

Add to the child file

```
onDelete: 'cascade'
```

and it worked.

ex.

/migrations/profile.js (The foreign key is 'user_id')

```
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('profiles', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      age: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      user_id: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',　　　　←　※　Add here.　※
      },
    })
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('profiles')
  },
}
```

Comment: This solution works, even I tested with sequelize-typescript. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't manage latest "sequelize": "^6.6.5" association cascade to work on existing postgres database with any of mentioned here tips so had to replace it with a model `beforeDestroy` hook like below

```
User.beforeDestroy(async user => {
  await Role.destroy({ where: { userId: user.id } })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer OP had added in the question:

> I accomplished this by adding constraint on database using `Alter`
> command, as `Add Foreign Key Constraint` through `migration` is an
> open [bug][1] in `sequelize`.
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE "Products"
> ADD CONSTRAINT "Products_CategoryId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("CategoryId")
> REFERENCES "Categories" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
> ON DELETE CASCADE
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As for sequelize ^6.6.5, because this topic is trending when searching for sequelize CASCADE :

I had to use the onDelete:'cascade' on both the hasMany & belongsTo association to make it work.

```
 Product.belongsTo(models.Category, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
 Category.hasMany(models.Product, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but this `{onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true}` didn't work for me.
If you are facing that same issue, then try to add a `reference` related code in your model's **migration** file.

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable("TravelDetails", {
            id: {
                ......
            },
            event_id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                onDelete: "CASCADE",
                references: {
                    model: "Events",
                    key: "id",
                    as: "eventData",
                },
            },
        });
    },
    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.dropTable("TravelDetails");
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you declaring the association between the models?

/models/index.js

```js
const Category  = require('./Category');
const Product = require('./Product');
const ProductTag = require('./ProductTag');
const Tag = require('./Tag');

Category.associate({Product});
Product.associate({Category,Tag});
Tag.associate({Product});

module.exports={Category,Product,ProductTag,Tag};
```

Model Category.js

```js
'use strict';
const {Model, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection.js');

class Category extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate({Product}) {
        // define association here
        console.log('Category associated with: Product');
        this.hasMany(Product, {
            foreignKey: 'category_id',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
    }
}

Category.init({
    category_id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
    category_name: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false}
}, {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    modelName: "Category",
});

module.exports = Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update only your product migration file.
In order when you delete category to be deleted with child products, you need to have in your product migration the following

```
...
categoryId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references : {
      model : 'Category',
      key : 'id'
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
},
...
```

no need to add this in model
{ onDelete: 'cascade' }

Answer (score 0):

1. Install sequelize-cli through npm.
2. After creating a database, make two models, e.g. Category & Products: sequelize model:create --name Category --attributes name:string etc.
3. Make sure your static method 'associate' inside Category model contains this: "static associate({Product}) {this.hasMany(Product, { foreignKey: 'categoryId', as: 'products', onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true });"
4. And for Product modal: "static associate({Category}) {this.belongsTo(Category, { foreignKey: 'categoryId', as: 'category'});
5. Also make sure your migration file -create-product.js contains this field:  categoryId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER,      allowNull: false}
6. Now run the terminal command: sequelize db:migrate
7. Write this countoller inside app.js:

   app.delete("/category/:id", async(req, res) => {
   const id = req.params.id;
   try {
   const category = await Category.findOne({
   where: { id },
   include: 'products'
   });
   await category.destroy();
   return res.json({ message: "Category is deleted!"});
   } catch (err) {
   return res.status(500).json({error: "Something went
   wrong"});
   }
   })
8. Launch the app with command: "node app.js" and test deleting on cascade in Postman.