# Sequelize onDelete not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, associations, has-many, sequelize.js

I have associations between two models defined as below:

For Contact Model (in a separate file)

```
classMethods: {
      associate: function (models){
         Contact.belongsTo(models.User)
      }
}
```

For User(in a separate file)

```
classMethods: {
     associate: function (models){
        User.hasMany(models.Contact, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
     }
}
```

The problem is when deleting the user the contact related to the user is not deleting any advice on what am I doing wrong would be helpful?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to define it the other way around.

```
Contact.belongsTo(models.Users, {
    foreignKeyConstraint: true
    , onDelete: 'cascade'
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The documentation is somehow misleading. In the doc, belongsTo does not have the onDelete='CASCADE' option, only hasMany has it. It should really be other way around.

Comment: Did this way work with `onDelete: 'cascade'` ? The [documentation](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/associations/index.html?highlight=onDelete#hasmanytarget-options) only shows the `cascade` option with the hasMany function. i am a bit confused.

Comment: I had to do following as documented (now). User.hasOne(Profile, {onDelete: 'cascade', hooks:true})

Comment: I had to do as commented here (adding to belongsTo) but also had to *remove* the use of `hasMany` in the other model's def. Then I got onDelete cascading.

Answer (score 0):

Update association to
`User.hasMany(models.Contact, { onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true })` to allow the hooks between associations to fire in order to enable the onDelete cascade. Adapted from the 
[sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html#associations):

> However, adding hooks: true explicitly tells Sequelize that
>   optimization is not of your concern and will perform a SELECT on the
>   associated objects and destroy each instance one by one in order to be
>   able to call the hooks with the right parameters.