# In NodeJS, is there a method similar to dependant: :destroy in Ruby for associated records?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I’m trying to delete tasks when delete a associated farmer.  I have read a sequelize docs and i have done the same solutions in there. But i can not delete tasks automatically. Also I have tried solutions in the following links:

[Sequelize onDelete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634139/sequelize-ondelete-not-working)

[Sequelize.js onDelete: 'cascade' is not deleting records sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128816/sequelize-js-ondelete-cascade-is-not-deleting-records-sequelize)

I'm using sequelizejs with mysql.

My models:

Task.js

```
'use strict';
var Farmer  = require('./farmer');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Task = sequelize.define('Task', {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        deadline: DataTypes.DATE,
        description: DataTypes.TEXT,
        FarmerId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                // This is a reference to another model
                model: Farmer,
                // This is the column name of the referenced model
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    }, {
    classMethods: {
       associate: function(models) {
          Task.belongsTo(models.Farmer, {foreignKey: 'FarmerId'});
          // associations can be defined here
       }
    }
   });
   return Task;
};
```

Farmer.js

```
'use strict';
var validator = require('validator');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Farmer = sequelize.define('Farmer', {
    username:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
    },
    address: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: { 
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
       unique: true,
       allowNull: false,
       validate: {
            isEmail: { args: true, msg: "not a valid email!" },
            len: { args: [0, 100], msg: "email can't be bigger than 100"},
        } 
    },
    phone:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
          Farmer.hasMany(models.Task, {onDelete: 'CASCADE', hooks:true});
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return Farmer;
};
```

What else can I do?

Also, Do I need to set ‘on delete cascade’ on mysql related table? If I don’t do it, sequelize define association onDelete doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

You can omit `FarmerId` in your definition of Task. Sequelize automatically knows that there's a `FarmerId` by associating Task with Farmer. Try that, everything else seems very usual.