# Destroy cascade is not working in Sequelize orm

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, cascade

I have two models created with Sequelize cli; first model is `user_number`, the second model is `emailSign`.

This is my `user_number` model:

```
    'use strict';
     module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
     var user_number = sequelize.define('user_number', {
     user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     callRoute_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     password: DataTypes.STRING,
     }, {
     underscored: true,
     classMethods: {
         associate: function(models) {
            // associations can be defined here
             user_number.hasMany(models.emailSign, {
                foreignKey: 'user_number_id',
                onDelete: "CASCADE",
             });
           }
           }
        });
      return user_number;
    };
```

This is my `emailSign` model:

```
      'use strict';
      module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
      var emailSign = sequelize.define('emailSign', {
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      user_number_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {
         underscored: true,
         classMethods: {
             associate: function(models) {
             // associations can be defined here
             emailSign.belongsTo(models.user_number, {
             foreignKey: 'user_number_id',

           })
         }
        }
      });
      return emailSign;
          };
```

I want destroy `user_number` to cascade remove `emailSign`. My code for destroy is

```
User_number.destroy({where:{id : 5}}).then(function(){

resp.status(200);
)
```

`user_number` with id 5 is removed, but `emailSign` is not removed.

How can I remove the related `emailSign` as well?

My Sequelize version is 3.30.4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634139/sequelize-ondelete-not-working

Comment: tanx but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

You should define onDelete action on belongsTo association

```
emailSign.belongsTo(models.user_number, {
     foreignKey: 'user_number_id',
     onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

Comment: how do i use it in migration file?

Comment: This doesn't work, and the [docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/hooks.html#associations) outline the cascade deletion on the hasMany side, like OP's code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue, but I came across this issue too. The cascade option should not be capitalized:

```
onDelete: 'cascade'
```

instead of

```
onDelete: 'CASCADE'
```

Comment: For which SQL engine?