# sequelize - How to set ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize. I have 2 models: `Category` and `User` like this:

```
const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        displayName: DataTypes.STRING
    });

    Category.associate = (models) => {
        models.Category.hasMany(models.Post, { foreignKey: 'categoryId' });
    };

const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        content: DataTypes.STRING
    });

    Post.associate = (models) => {
        models.Post.belongsTo(models.Category, {
            foreignKey: 'categoryId',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
    };
```

The init code above does create 2 tables, with `categoryId` as the foreign key referencing `Category` of `Post`. But the resultant script includes:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`categoryId`) REFERENCES `Categories` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Instead of `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Please tell me what is wrong here and how to set `ON DELETE CASCADE` on that foreign key attribute.

Comment: I think you need to put the on delete option on the Category model, please check [this answer (Possible Duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128816/sequelize-js-ondelete-cascade-is-not-deleting-records-sequelize)

Answer (score -1):

1. Install sequelize-cli through npm.
2. After creating a database, make two models, e.g. Category & Products: sequelize model:create --name Category --attributes name:sting etc.
3. Make sure your static method 'associate' inside Category model contains this: "static associate({Product}) {this.hasMany(Product, { foreignKey: 'categoryId', as: 'products', onDelete: 'cascade', hooks: true });"
4. And for Product modal: "static associate({Category}) {this.belongsTo(Category, { foreignKey: 'categoryId', as: 'category'});
5. Also make sure your migration file -create-product.js contains this field: categoryId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false}
6. Now run the terminal command: sequelize db:migrate
7. Write this countoller inside app.js:

   app.delete("/category/:id", async(req, res) => { const id =
   req.params.id; try { const category = await
   Category.findOne({ where: { id }, include: 'products' });
   await category.destroy(); return res.json({ message:
   "Category is deleted!"}); } catch (err) { return
   res.status(500).json({error: "Something went wrong"}); } })
8. Launch the app with command: "node app.js" and test deleting on cascade in Postman.