# sequlize ignore deleting associate table data

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using `Sequlize` PostgreSQL.
I have some table below

```
Campaign( id, title )

BPCampaign( id, campaign_Id(forigen_key) )

Customer( id, name, campaign_id(forignkey) )

Tasks( id, customer_id(forign_key) )
```

models => https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KDyC92brNQ/

I am trying to delete Campaign and BPCampaign..

```
    try {
        await BPCampaign.destroy({
            where:{
                campaign_id: req.params.id
            }
        }, { transaction: t });

        await Campaign.destroy({
            where:{
                id: req.params.id
            }
        },{ transaction: t })

        await t.commit().then(v=>{
            Methods.successResponse(req, res, v)
        }).catch(err=>{
            ErrorResMethods.errorResponse(req, res, err)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await t.rollback();
    }
```

It is not working throwing an error like that..

```
"campaigns" violates foreign key constraint "customers_campaign_id_fkey" on table "customers"
```

I have understood that Customer table have forign key campaign_id that why it is not deleting.

How can I delete from Bpcampaign and Campaign table without deleting from other related table?

Comment: You have to use  onDelete: 'CASCADE' in your model files where foreign key references are mentioned.

Comment: what will be the solution then ?

Comment: models >>> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KDyC92brNQ/

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23128816/sequelize-js-ondelete-cascade-is-not-deleting-records-sequelize

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I am getting an idea about my probem but not actually my answer